# Java MD5 implementation hashes strings to incorrect values

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, md5

I looked at multiple websites to find what the MD5 algorithm is. Then I used what I learned to write a method in Java that can compute the MD5 hash of a given input. I tried changing certain parts of the code that I thought was incorrect but I still couldn't get the correct hash values for some of the Strings I tried. Here is my code:

```
    import java.security.MessageDigest;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

    class MD5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String[] msgs = new String[] { "", "md5", "MD5", "Java",
                "MessageDigest5", "1234", "123abc", "0123456789abcdef" };
        String[] strings = new String[msgs.length + args.length];
        System.arraycopy(msgs, 0, strings, 0, msgs.length);
        for (int i = msgs.length; i < strings.length; ++i)
            strings[i] = args[i - msgs.length];
        for (String s : strings) {
            System.out.print("MD5(\"" + s + "\") = ");
            byte[] md5 = md5(s.getBytes());
            byte[] java = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.getBytes());
            StringBuilder sbmd5 = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sbjava = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
                sbmd5.append(String.format("%02x", md5[i] & 0xff));
                sbjava.append(String.format("%02x", java[i] & 0xff));
            }
            System.out.print("Java(" + sbjava.toString() + ") MD5(");
            System.out.print(sbmd5.toString() + ")");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] md5(byte[] data) {
        if (data == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        byte[] padding = new byte[] { (byte) 0x80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] SHIFT = new int[] { 7, 12, 17, 22, 5, 9, 14, 20, 4, 11, 16, 23,
                6, 10, 15, 21 };
        int[] TABLE = new int[64];
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
            TABLE[i] = (int) (long) ((1L << 32) * Math.abs(Math.sin(i + 1)));
        int A = 0x67452301; // 01234567
        int B = 0xefcdab89; // 89abcdef
        int C = 0x98badcfe; // fedcba98
        int D = 0x10325476; // 76543210
        // int A = 0x01234567;
        // int B = 0x89abcdef;
        // int C = 0xfedcba98;
        // int D = 0x76543210;
        byte[] msg = new byte[data.length + 64 - (data.length % 64)];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, msg, 0, data.length);
        int padPos = 0;
        for (int i = data.length; i < msg.length; ++i)
            msg[i] = padding[padPos++];
        for (int i = 0; i < msg.length >>> 6; ++i) {
            int[] words = new int[16];
            int msgStart = i << 6;
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j) {
                int k = j << 2;
                int begin = msgStart + k;
                words[j] = msg[begin] + (msg[begin + 1] << 8)
                        + (msg[begin + 2] << 16) + (msg[begin + 3] << 24);
            }
            int a0 = A;
            int b0 = B;
            int c0 = C;
            int d0 = D;
            for (int j = 0; j < 64; ++j) {
                int j16 = j >>> 4;
                int F;
                int index;
                switch (j16) {
                case 0:
                    F = (b0 & c0) | (~b0 & d0);
                    // F = d0 ^ (b0 & (c0 ^ d0));
                    index = j;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    F = (b0 & d0) | (c0 & ~d0);
                    // F = c0 ^ (d0 & (b0 ^ c0));
                    index = ((j * 5) + 1) & 15;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    F = b0 ^ c0 ^ d0;
                    index = ((j * 3) + 5) & 15;
                    break;
                default:
                    F = c0 ^ (b0 | ~d0);
                    index = (j * 7) & 15;
                    break;
                }
                int rotateValue = A + F + words[index] + TABLE[j];
                int rotateDistance = SHIFT[(j16 << 2) | (j & 3)];
                int temp = B
                        + ((rotateValue << rotateDistance) | (rotateValue >>> (32 - rotateDistance)));
                A = D;
                D = C;
                C = B;
                B = temp;
            }
            A += a0;
            B += b0;
            C += c0;
            D += d0;
        }
        byte[] result = new byte[16];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            int n = i == 0 ? A : (i == 1 ? B : (i == 2 ? C : D));
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                result[index++] = (byte) n;
                n >>>= 8;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with it but here is the output. I hashed the same set of strings in both my implementation and java.security.MessageDigest to compare the hashes.

```
MD5("") = Java(d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e) MD5(6195f07125a3dab6a14e8e929a0ac5bf)
MD5("md5") = Java(1bc29b36f623ba82aaf6724fd3b16718) MD5(f382be5a669dd9ce3095a4aa2e55ff18)
MD5("MD5") = Java(7f138a09169b250e9dcb378140907378) MD5(af2ade546a995a239c94f5776393bfdd)
MD5("Java") = Java(d52387880e1ea22817a72d3759213819) MD5(f512715d4bc0728fd50994d6583d6370)
MD5("MessageDigest5") = Java(c39f3b584476f0fd9303fe2cba34a1de) MD5(85e2d27519fbf97c3f988e9ccb9564a6)
MD5("1234") = Java(81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055) MD5(51e22a66d259c84c920d11f3b1048263)
MD5("123abc") = Java(a906449d5769fa7361d7ecc6aa3f6d28) MD5(e1254819f3127907cb3e95b3fa3b2e68)
MD5("0123456789abcdef") = Java(4032af8d61035123906e58e067140cc5) MD5(28fcda2be1f449185c73222e3a6e5ca4)
```

Comment: Why you try to reinvent the wheel? :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised.

Comment: @EJP *If* that still existed as a reason for being off topic. But it could be off topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com...

Comment: @owlstead It is the reason I have given, and if that is no longer a valid reason this site is going to silt up very rapidly.

Comment: You certainly should specify a specific encoding when turning strings to bytes. In your case ASCII or UTF-8 would be most appropriate.

Comment: @owlstead It's not working code, so it doesn't belong on codereview.

Comment: @EJP OK, closing, as this is given as a prime reason for closing a question: ["Programming, but not code dumps"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns). Sorry, new user, but it seems off topic - it is not likely to benefit other users. Cryptography is hard; I would suggest you use another implementation and print out the *intermediate states*. Then compare where you go wrong...

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public void encrypt(){
    String password = new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());

    MessageDigest algorithm = null;
    try {
        algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(pe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    algorithm.reset();
    algorithm.update(password.getBytes());
    byte bytes [] = algorithm.digest();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (byte b : bytes){
         String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & b);
         if (hex.length() == 1)
             sb.append('0');
         sb.append(hex);
    }
    String result = sb.toString();
    jTextArea1.setText(result);

}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, you try to force another method on a user who is trying to learn something about hashing by providing him a standard library function which will not help him learn anything at all, your code is not formatted which makes it harder to read, your code is incomplete, and on top of all of that, you have literally no explanation. I would give this 2 downvotes if I could.